# Financial Service Addendum in GCP ? (PSEE in France)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, providers

Do you know if Google Cloud Plateforme can add a specific addendum relative to the Financial requirements in this contacts ?

For instance, when a client is a Financial Institution (a Bank for instance) AWS is able to add to its T&C an addendum. They call it a Financial Service Addendum.

This helps banks to meet their compliance requirements.
It includes various topics like a right of access and audit, the list of subcontractors,...

But, is Google Cloud Plateform is able to do the same ?

(For SEO purpose : For french guys, we call that the PSEE)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for their compliance information (listing the various audit methods & results, subcontractors, access rights, etc).  See: https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/#/industries=Financial_Services

Comment: Thank @Ruscal, I checked this page before, but this kind of addendum seems not a norm that a google could endorses, but more really in paragraph added in the contract between them and us.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what you're looking for, but last GCP project I worked on the contract simply referenced these documents (something like "all subcontractors, their ability to access customer data, and the conditions on that access are listed in the SOC 70 controls published at <url>". Which effective meant this was part of the contract.  If you mean can the add custom riders on the boilerplate contacts, the answer is yes, just have to work with your account rep.

Answer (score 1):

I post the answer for the next person who is wondering the same question :

We meet the France's GCP salesman dedicated to the FinTech companies and he confirms to us that Google is able to add this specific addendum (the famous FSEE).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should contact [sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) they should be able to provide the reports needed but first you will need to sign a NDA.